# FFMEPG - Overlay an image and a video on another video encode 2 pass

Tags: ffmpeg

This is my nightmare :

```
for %%f in (*.avi) do (
ffmpeg -y ^
-i "%%f" ^
-pix_fmt yuv420p ^
-c:v libx264 ^
-pass 1 ^
-an ^
-preset slow -profile:v high -level 4.0 -tune animation ^
-b:v 10000k -minrate 10000k -maxrate 20000k -bufsize 20000k -g 15 -keyint_min 8 -sc_threshold 0 ^
-r 30 -bf 2 ^
-fast-pskip 1 ^
-threads 4 ^
-f rawvideo NUL && ^
ffmpeg -y ^
-i "%%f" ^
-i "input.png" ^
-i "input.mp4" ^
-pix_fmt yuv420p ^
-c:v libx264 ^
-pass 2 ^
-preset slow -profile:v high -level 4.0 -tune animation ^
-fast-pskip 0 ^
-c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 2 -r:a 48000 ^
-b:v 10000k -minrate 10000k -maxrate 20000k -bufsize 20000k -g 15 -keyint_min 8 -sc_threshold 0 ^
-bf 2 ^
-me_method umh -qmin 5 -deblock 0:0:0 ^
-threads 4 ^
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=enable='between(t,0,4)'[o1]; [2:v] scale=0.5*iw:0.5*ih; [o1][2:v] overlay=enable='between(t,0,4)'" ^
-color_primaries bt709 -color_trc bt709 -colorspace bt709 ^
"%%~nf_01.mp4"
)
```

I have two overlays in the same row, overlay on the video like the image bellow :
[image]

[on the top]This overlay must be encoded or not (it depend of the workflow) at 85% of luminosity.
[Left]In half-gray you could see the position for the video which must not encoded again. [Right] you see the typo on overlay. 
[Background] (gray checker) you see the encoded video in two pass...

I don't know how to do that so I abort it, maybe you find the solution and solve it !

Answer (score 0):

Answer : it's just impossible in libx264 of FFMPEG !